# Count the integers that conform another integer

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I have to count all the integers than conform to integer *A*.

We say that integer *B* conforms to integer *A* if, in all positions where *A* has bits set to 1, *B* has corresponding bits set to 1.

If I have a binary string like this one: `0 0 0 1 0 1` (5 in decimal). A conforming integer would be: `0 0 0 1 1 1`, or `1 0 0 1 0 1`. The following is not a conforming integer: `0 1 0 0 0 1`.

If I have to count all the numbers of 6 bits that conform `0 0 0 1 0 1` I get this table of candidates:

```
5 4 3 2 1 0 <= base 2 exponent
---------------
0 0 0 1 1 1 - 1
0 0 1 1 0 1 - 3
0 1 0 1 0 1 - 4
1 0 0 1 0 1 - 5

0 0 1 1 1 1 - 1, 3
0 1 0 1 1 1 - 1, 4
1 0 0 1 1 1 - 1, 5

0 1 1 1 1 1 - 1, 3, 4
1 0 1 1 1 1 - 1, 3, 5

1 1 1 1 1 1 - 1, 3, 4, 5
    
1 1 0 1 1 1 - 1, 4, 5

0 1 1 1 0 1 - 3, 4
1 0 1 1 0 1 - 3, 5

1 1 1 1 0 1 - 3, 4, 5

1 1 0 1 0 1 - 4, 5
```

If I have 4 zeros in `0 0 0 1 0 1` I get 15 different numbers that conform with the given integer. **Note**: I have to add one because the number `0 0 0 1 0 1` conforms itself. So, there are 16 numbers that conforms `0 0 0 1 0 1`.

Is there any formula to compute this?

I think it could be some combinatorial analysis because it is: (4) + (3 + 2 + 1 + 1) + (2 + 1) + (1). But I have no idea.

But all the above explanation is about if you need to know more about what I have to do.

Another example.

Integer A: `00 0000 1100 0110 1101 1110 0000 0001`

Integer B: `00 0000 1111 0111 1101 1110 0000 1111`

Integer B *conforms* integer A.

Comment: You must have counted incorrectly.  $14$?  Count again.  Consider the following... rather than counting ways to extend 000101, remove the original 1's... we now have four positions.  Given a way of changing the zero bits, for example as $abcd$, we can go back to the original by putting those original $1$'s back in place as $abc1d1$.  You should be able to see clearly that $abcd$ can take results 0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101, ... on up to 1111.  You should recognize this list...

Comment: It is also unclear whether you intend to ignore the case of 0000... according to your definition I would have rather expected 000101 to "conform" to itself.  You did not specify that a number does not conform to itself and did not specify that you are wanting to count numbers *different* than the original number.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have all the possible 6 bits values without repetition that conforms the value `0 0 0 1 0 1`.

Comment: You didn't list $1 1 0 1 1 1$, which adds bits $1$, $4$, and $5$. In general, if you have $n$ $0$ bits, there are $2^n$ numbers that conform (including the original number). In this case, we have $2^4 = 16$ numbers ($15$ if we don't include the original number). ¶ Incidentally, I suspect that @JMoravitz read the problem accurately; they probably meant to ask whether you intended to ignore the case where no $1$ bits were *added* (rather than no bits at all were set to $1$).

Comment: Exactly.  The punchline should be that even if the original phrasing of a question may seem foreign, you can many times (*especially with elementary combinatorics questions*) rephrase the question into something you *do* know... in this case for example counting how many binary numbers there are in the list 0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, ... , 1111 which you should know is $2^4=16$.  Perhaps even easier, you could phrase it as a multiplication principle question "pick whether we flip the first zero or not" then "pick whether we flip the second zero or not" etc.. giving $2\times \cdots \times 2 = 2^n$

Comment: So, for the example of `00 0000 1100 0110 1101 1110 0000 0001`, there are $19$ zeroes, and so $19$ separate opportunities to flip or not flip, giving $2^{19}$ different yes/no sequences of whether we flip the zero bits or not (*including the answer of all no*)

Comment: As for how you were trying to brute force the count and represent this as a sum... if you were to organize it as having flipped no bits, having flipped one bit, having flipped two bits, etc... you will have had the sum $1+4+6+4+1=16$... or more generally the sum $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\dots+\binom{n}{n}=2^n$, the special case of the binomial theorem expansion of $(1+1)^n$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm not trying to brute force or anything. I've just written down what I have done. I'm doing my best because I haven't studied maths for more than 20 years. I'm trying to solve a problem and I have shared with you the problem, what I have to find and what I have tried.

Comment: Listing them out by hand and counting with your fingers and toes is an example of what we mean when we say "brute force" in maths.  In any event, you should have your answer now.

Comment: OK. Sorry for the misunderstanding.